# Prove that there exists a non-zero vector u such that F(u)=0 without dimensional equations

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Consider the linear transformation $T:U \to V$ where U and V are vector spaces, with $dim(V)< dim(U) < \infty$. show that there's a $u$ such that $T(u) = 0$

I was able to prove this using that $dim(U) = dim(Ker(T)) +dim(Im(T))$. However now I have to show this without using this theorem (at least not directly), but I don't know how to begin, all my attempts end up using the Ker, and Image.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I found out another approach, and one that is much simpler than the one that I was searching.

Consider the transformation $T : U \to V$ where V and U are vector spaces.

Notice that $\text{dim}_{K} V < \text{dim}_{K}U < \infty$ so should exist a transformation that $T(u_1 + \dots + u_n) = 0$ where $n$ is defined by $\text{dim}_{K} U$, but notice that the $\text{dim}_{K}V < \text{dim}_{K}U$ so should exist a coefficient that's different from zero (in the result), so that the result is equal to zero (since is linearly dependent).

But since it's a linear transformation, we have $c_1T(u_1) + \dots + c_{n}T(u_n) = T(c_{1}u_1 + \dots + c_{n}u_{n}) = 0$ but $u_{1} \dots u_{n}$ is a basis and therefore is linearly independent, so a vector that's different from zero exists so that the transformation is equal to zero.

Answer (score 2):

First, you should prove that there is a $u \neq 0$ such that $T(u)=0$. If it is not true, then you can check that $U$ is isomorphic to its image under $T$. Therefore, $U$ can be viewed as a subspace of $V$, which is a contradiction.

Comment: Thanks! I forgot that I could use isomorphism.